# CPU usage for two different methods of converting list to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science, cpu-usage

I have a list of ~250 long-ish strings (avg about 80 chars each).  I'm converting the whole list to a single string and it's taking forever.  1) I'm not sure why it's taking so long and 2) why would the following two methods differ in CPU utilization so much (first way uses ~50% (of a core, I think) and the second uses ~100%)

First method:

`text = "".join(str(i) for i in text)`

Second method:

`text = [text.extend(line) for line in text]`

I realize the second method returns a list but that's okay because it's only one element and I can deal with that easily.

Comment: The second one is not a correct solution to the problem. It doesn't convert a list to a string at all, and it is an infinite loop because it iterates over a list which keeps growing. It takes *literally* forever, at least until you run out of memory.

Comment: `text = [text.extend(line) for line in text]` is *not* the way you should be using list comprehensions. Do **not use list comprehensions for side effects**. Anyway, what do you mean by "taking forever"? My own profiling on my 3 year old Macbook is taking about 100 microseconds for a list with your specifications...

Comment: @kaya3 good catch. I suppose *only that second approach* is taking forever...

Comment: @kaya3 yep, woops.  I see the infinite loop.  The second method is taking over 20 minutes before I manually interrupt it.

Comment: And when you manually interrupt it, I expect you'll find that `len(text)` is a rather large number; certainly not one element.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How is that operation taking 100microseconds?  Have you changed the method in some way?  It takes 20 minutes before I interrupt it.

Comment: @kaya3 you're right.  Doesn't that mean neither method works then?  I don't want a list of characters, I want a single string.

Comment: The first method works, and gives you a single string. It is the proper way to join a list into a single string in Python. If the list already contains strings, then you can just write `"".join(text)` without the generator expression, though. I don't know why you thought that these two methods did the same thing.

Comment: @SamDillard I was timing the first method. Your question wasn't clear to me when I read it, but after kaya3 pointed out that you were `.extend`ing the same `list` you were iterating over, it now makes sense

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my question to you was how you were completing that task (the one that works) within that short of a time period.  That way was taking many minutes for me...again, before I stopped it so I don't know how long it really would have taken.

Comment: @SamDillard `text = "".join(str(i) for i in text)` is taking many minutes for you???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yep.  Still haven't seen it complete :/

Comment: You have to provide a [mcve] because that cannot be for the inputs you describe